# How do I write test to check the browser scrolls down using webdriver, testng?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I have a link that stays on same page but scrolls down the screen

if you go to websiste test.naimi.me and click here:
[image: kk]

the link should scroll you down a little bit, how to test this action in selenium webdriver, i use testng and write in java.

EDIT:@Helping hands

```
    package erjan.test.naimi.me;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.Assert;
public class SpecialistLoads {
    WebDriver firefox ;
  @Test
  public void main() {
      //By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/astana/\"]/img") )) ;
      WebElement all_specs = firefox.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href=\"/astana/#specialists\"]")) ;



      all_specs.click();
      String all_specalists_url = firefox.getCurrentUrl();
      Assert.assertEquals(all_specs, all_specialists_url );
  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      firefox = new  FirefoxDriver() ;
      firefox.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      //Launch the website
      firefox.get("http://test.naimi.me");
  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      firefox.quit();

  }

}
```

The link the red arrow points to has html code:

`a data-toggle="menu" href="/astana/#specialists">Все специалисты</a>`

Comment: How you have tried? can you please share you code?

Comment: @HelpingHands, yes, just a sec

Comment: @HelpingHands, so i use testNG, i open firefox in beforeMethod, close in afterMethod, and do actual test in test annotation

Comment: @ERJAN- Yes , thanks for code sharing , please check my update answer.

Answer (score 1):

To test it, I would make usage of an indirect check.

Verify if a botton element of the page is visible after activating the link. I am more comfortable with the python code but in java the call should be:

`WebElement.isDisplayed()` to check if an element is visible

> isDisplayed() is the method used to verify presence of a web element
>   within the webpage. The method is designed to result a Boolean value
>   with each success and failure. The method returns a “true” value if
>   the specified web element is present on the web page and a “false”
>   value if the web element is not present on the web page.

Example:

```
boolean footer_loaded=driver.findElement(By.id(“footer”)).isDisplayed();
```

Answer (score 1):

If link is not visible when page load then you can use **isdisplayed** method like below :

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath(yourlinkxpath"));

If(link.isDisplayed())
{
   // Write code to click on link

}
else
{

  // Write code to skip it
}
```

To find link element you can use Id , xpath , class anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport by [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect). You'll need to use driver.executeScript() for that.

Comment: very interesting approach. Is it bonded to a specific browser ?

Comment: For only checking the current position relative to the viewport it should be quite common according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect#Browser_compatibility